# sudo service apache2 stop no longer works?

Tags: apache2, xampp

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 last month after a long layoff (April 2014) from programming PHP scripts accessing a MySql database. I have always installed and used XAMPP for years. When starting XAMPP with

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

XAMPP attempts to start its own Apache2, MySql and ProFTP. If another webserver, mysql or ftp is already running, XAMPP fails to start.

Now I am informed that another web server and FTP are already running; I have encountered this in the past.  But previously I was able to

```
sudo service apache2 stop    
sudo service mysqld stop    
sudo service ftpd stop    
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

and XAMPP would start and run as expected. But now `apache2` and `ftp` are unrecognized services, And I can't even find them in `/etc/init.d` or using `initctl list` or anywhere.

Has it been renamed ?

Comment: They haven't been renamed. Did you install the apache2 packages as well, alongside XAMPP? What does `sudo netstat -tnlp` say?

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I found that rebooting the system from shutdown fixed the problem. I think it was caused by the wifi USB I am using (no ethernet available) being inserted after booting.  If I boot with the USB inserted, the procedure I usually use works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use the convenience LAMPP / XAMPP packages; I just installed apache2, mysql, etc, normally.  That said, for me, `sudo service apache2 restart` works.